# Unlock OS X keychain without a password

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild, codesign

I'm doing a remote/automated build<sup>[1]</sup> of my Xcode projects<sup>[2]</sup> and in order to sign my apps, I add this line before the build.

```
security unlock-keychain -p keychainpassword
```

This works fine, and unlocks the SYSTEM keychains where the certificates are stored, but it's exposing the password for the user which the build agent is running on in the [TeamCity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity) interface for all to see.

The build process is running as a logged in user, and is self-contained... is there a way I can unlock the system/default keychain without providing the password?

I've just had a thought. What if I moved the certificates into the login's keychain (instead of system)? Would I still have to unlock it with a password?

Is this possible at all? Or should I set up a user which cannot do any damage and just build and do nothing else and expose that user's password?

[1] Using TeamCity, but irrelevant.

[2] iPhone projects, but again irrelevant.

Comment: If it's really that important to you, you could write a little app that unlocks the keychain and reads the password from a file that is read-only for the user and no access for all others. That way the password is not exposed in the process list.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to build with a regular (non-admin) user, and make that user have no password. Then, you can auto-login as that user on your build system.

Another alternative is to store the password in an environment variable, but that barely hides the password.

If you have a regular user with no password, and you add the certificates to the Login keychain, you should be able to build remotely / automatically / unattended with no issues, including code-signing.

Answer (score 0):

`security unlock-keychain` on its own prompts for the password.